# UITableView bigger than screen inside UIPageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

Lately I'm pulling my hair out because of this. I'm still a rookie iOS Developer therefore a simple solution would be appreciated.

I have a UIPageViewController with three views, the middle view is a UITableView which i populate with data programmatically and try to make a layout like a grid. When the UITableView has too many data the information gets outside of the screen.

[image]

I've tried to disable auto layout and add the UITableView to a UIScrollView, enabling the UITableView to scroll horizontal. I've managed to do that but somehow the interaction is messy and most of the times when trying to horizontal scroll the table it catches the UIPageViewController interaction. Also the vertical scroll of the table does not respond well too.

Is there a known solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing a few things I ended up with a acceptable solution using autolayout.

So first I added a UIScrollView and added the UITableView inside the UIScrollView.
I've enabled the Paging and disabled the Bounce Horizontally in the UIScrollView.

In the UITableView I've basically disabled everything relative to bouncing paging and scrolling.

Since the data is being populated programmatically to be some sort of a grid I have to know the total width of the longest row for that I've created a few methods to calculate the maximum width and arrange the labels.

I also created constraints for the table Width and Height which I calculate and update after all the calculations are done.

```
-(void) ArrangeTable
{
    for (int i= 0; i < [arrayTable count]; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j< [[arrayTable objectAtIndex:i ] count]; j++) {
            UILabel * nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 8.0, 95.0, 30.0)];
            [nameLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayTable objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j]]];
            [nameLabel sizeToFit];

            float widthIs = [nameLabel.text
                         boundingRectWithSize:nameLabel.frame.size
                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                         attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:nameLabel.font }
                         context:nil].size.width;
            [self alignLabels:j currentWidth:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: widthIs]];
        }
    }
}

-(void) alignLabels:(int)colNumber currentWidth:(NSNumber*)labelWidth
{
    if(colNumber >= [arrayLabelWidth count])
    {
        //Insert without position
        [arrayLabelWidth addObject:labelWidth];

    }else if ([labelWidth floatValue] > [[arrayLabelWidth objectAtIndex:colNumber] floatValue] )
    {
        [arrayLabelWidth replaceObjectAtIndex:colNumber withObject:labelWidth];
    }
}

-(void) setMaxRowWidth
{
    float widthTV =[[arrayLabelWidth valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"] floatValue] + ([arrayLabelWidth count]) * 10;
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    float heightTV = [self tableViewHeight];

    if(widthTV > screenRect.size.width)
    {
        tvWidth.constant =  widthTV;
        //svWidth.constant = valueTV;
    }else{
        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
            //DO Portrait
            tvWidth.constant =  screenRect.size.width;
        }else{
            //DO Landscape
            float calc = screenRect.size.width - self.view.frame.size.width;
            tvWidth.constant =  screenRect.size.width - calc;
        }
    }
    tvHeight.constant = heightTV;

}

- (CGFloat)tableViewHeight
{
    [tablePod layoutIfNeeded];
    return [tablePod contentSize].height;
}
```